# How do I update date without changing the older date value in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, sql-update

I'm creating a withdraw function where user can only withdraw their money in bulk. If they have their transaction in the same day. They can only withdraw it the day after today. Meaning that they cannot withdraw their money in the same day that they have make their transaction. But I got a problem when user wants to withdraw their money. The older date_claim got changed too.

```
---------------------
|id   |transac_date | total | status  | date_claim |
--------------------------------------------------
|abc1 | 2020-10-07  | 98   | claimed  | 2020-10-10 |
|abc1 | 2020-10-22  | 124  |unclaimed | null       |
|abc1 | 2020-10-24  | 145  |unclaimed | null       |
```

in this case user are trying to claim the `transaction date on 2020-10-22`

```
if(isset($_POST['withdraw']))
{
   $id= $_GET['id'];
   $sql="UPDATE tbl_kqd SET status ='claimed', date_claim = CURRENT_DATE()
        WHERE id = '$id' AND 
        DATE(transac_date) !=CURRENT_DATE() ";
   $sql_claim = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
   
   if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0){
    echo "<script>alert('Successfully Claimed!')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location = 'claim.php'</script>";  
   }
  else
    echo "<script>alert('Please try tomorrow!')</script>";
}


//the output


---------------------
|id   |transac_date | total | status  | date_claim |
--------------------------------------------------
|abc1 | 2020-10-07  | 98   | claimed  | 2020-10-24 |
|abc1 | 2020-10-22  | 124  | claimed  | 2020-10-24 |
|abc1 | 2020-10-24  | 145  |unclaimed | null       |
```

the query makes the older date changed too. I don't want it to change date that has been claimed. How do I fix this problem?

In database I declare the `date_claim as date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to update the first "unclaimed" row for the given `id` and whose `transac_date` is different than today. Here is one way to phrase this:

```
update tbl_kqd 
set status ='claimed', date_claim = current_date()
where id = ? and transac_date <> current_date and status = 'unclaimed'
order by transac_date 
limit 1
```

MySQL supports `order by` in `update` statements.

Answer (score 0):

That's happen because your Id is the same on the 3 rows !! make a unique id for every row will fix it.

```
---------------------
|id   |transac_date | total | status  | date_claim |
--------------------------------------------------
|abc1 | 2020-10-07  | 98   | claimed  | 2020-10-24 |
|abc2 | 2020-10-22  | 124  | claimed  | 2020-10-24 |
|abc3 | 2020-10-24  | 145  |unclaimed | null       |
```

Comment: thank you for your solution but like I said above `I'm creating a withdraw function where user can only withdraw their money in bulk.` meaning that they gonna have to use the same id but different transaction. And I'm creating update withdraw by bulk meaning that. If the status is `unclaimed` they can claim it using the same id. changing the id will definitely going to change the purpose of the function.

Comment: I understand your solution completely thank you. I know there is the transaction id,  but the transaction id are not going to work. because every id is different  and i have to update the row one by one. instead of updating it by bulk.

Comment: if you have the same id so you should make a Foreign key , not storing them like that !!